# Sending data from an Android to a Laptop

Tags: java, android, eclipse, wireless

Pretty much everything is in the title here.

I have an android tablet, a windows laptop, both are conntected to the same router and I'd like my app send images and text to the laptop.

This possible? And if so, how?

Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can:

- Develop server/client applications that communicate via sockets.

Or

- Set up an ftp server in your laptop, and develop an application that uploads the files to the ftp.

There are a lot of other alternatives, but these two are the pretty straight forward ones.

Comment: ftp sounds best for my purposes. Thanks. I guess it was a pretty stupid question on my part. I clearly just forgot that I'm still using java.